# Find the image of set $A=\{(x,y)\,|\, x^2+y^2= 1 \}$ under the linear transformation $T(x,y)=(x-2y,2x)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Find the image of set $A=\{(x,y)\,|\, x^2+y^2= 1 \}$ under the linear transformation  $$T(x,y)=(x-2y,2x)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}x  \\ y  \end{pmatrix} $$

intuitivity I see that the image is the parallelogram with vertex in the points $T(1,0)=(1,2)$, $T(0,1)=(-2,0)$, $T(-1,0)=(-1,-2)$, $T(0,-1)=(2,0)$.

I try with parametrizing, with polar coordinates and with change variables $u=x-2y$, $v=2x$ but i can't find a decent proof of this.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parametrize:

$\star)$: $x=r \cos(t);$ $ y= r\sin(t).$

Transformation:

$X=r\cos(t) - 2 r\sin(t);$  $Y= 2r\cos(t)$; where $0< r \le 1, 0\le t \le 2π.$

Eliminate $t$ to find an equation in $X,Y.$

Using $\star)$, set $r= 1$ for the boundary:

1) $(-1/2)(X -Y/2) = \sin(t).$

2) $Y/2 = cos(t)$.

Squaring and adding:

$X^2 - XY +(5/4)Y^2 = 4;$

This is an equation of a rotated ellipse centered at (0,0).

Note:

If $A^2-4AC<0,$ $A,C>0$,  then

$AX^2 +BXY +CY^2 =1$ is an ellipse rotated about the origin.

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think that the result is a parallelogram? The unit circle can be parametrized as $(\cos t,\sin t)$ and so performing the matrix multiplication $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & -2 \\ 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\cos t  \\ \sin t  \end{pmatrix}\, , $$ we arrive at $x=\cos t-2\sin t$ and $y=2\cos t$, which is an ellipse